# objective c - making a NSManagedObject and regular NSObject classes that inherit from the same parent class

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my iPhone app I have two viewControllers: 
viewController1 has a tableView that shows a list of Item1 objects
viewController2 has a tableView that shows a list of Item2 objects

Where Item1 class and Item2 class inherit from the abstract class ParentItem.

Now I want to make Item2 object a NSManagedObject so I can save it on the device and make the viewController2 use a NSFetchedResultsController to load its tableView with Item2 objects.

But I don't want Item1 to be a NSManagedObject, I want to use it as regular object.

The problem is that if I create ParentItem class as NSManagedObject then Item1 class will also be a NSManagedObject and I can't use it as a regular object (I mean I wont be able to create an Item1 object with regular alloc-init, or can I???)

And if I create ParentItem class as regular NSObject, then Item2 class will also be regular NSObject.

Comment: Do you need some shared implementation, or just a shared interface? For a shared interface you could just use a protocol.

Comment: I also need shared implementation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you most likely need is an interface that the two class's can implement. I'll use the example of a person:

```
@protocol PersonInterface <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

**Class inheriting from `NSObject`**

```
@interface NonManagedPerson : NSObject <PersonInterface>
@end

@implementation NonManagedPerson

@synthesize firstName = _firstName;
@synthesize lastName  = _lastName;

@end
```

**Class inheriting from `NSManagedObject`**

```
@interface ManagedPerson : NSManagedObject <PersonInterface>
@end

@implementation ManagedPerson

@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;

@end
```

Now if an object needs to use either of these classes it does not care what it's supertype it, it will only care that the object responds to `-firstName`, `-lastName`, `-setFirstName` or `-setLastName`.

To allow this flexibility you need to be ensuring that the objects you want to use conform to the interface as you are no longer bothered about a specific type e.g.:

```
@interface FootballClub : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<PersonInterface> clubManager;

// .. other properties

@end
```

---

**Update**

To get shared implementation you could consider composition/delegation.

**Composition**

You make another class that encapsulates the common work and then have it as an available as an ivar to be used in your class.

**Delegation**

Do the same as other common elements, such as `UITableView`. At certain points it calls out to it's `datasource` (any element that implements the required methods of `<UITableViewDatasource>`) to ask for something to be done. You can then have two objects use the same class as a datasource and the implementation will be shared.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but you didn't adjust the inheritance issue.. what if ManagedPerson and NonManagedPerson have the same implementation to doSomthing method?

Comment: Can I have an example? Maybe composition of delegation would help you out in these instances

Comment: In my case ManagedPerson and NonManagedPerson have some shard implementation this is why i made them inherit from a parent object that implement the shard methods. The problem with using only the interface is that i will have to duplicate the same implementation in both of them.

Comment: Composition would be making a third class, call it MyPersonImplementation, put all the shared implementation in there, then give each of the top-level classes an ivar of type MyPerson which they can then forward calls of methods in PersonInterface to.  Another option is to make the shared implementation just a bunch of C functions and have each top-level class's methods call the C functions.  There's plenty of literature out there on object composition, like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition